# JFrame always on top, but below another jframe?

Tags: java, jframe

My problem is, that I have 3 different JFrames (I can not put 3 in one because all include ImageIcons and Mouslisteners). When I open the programm they are exactly where I want them to be, but when I click on the JFrame in the background it appears in the foreground and the others are moving to the background..

I know that I can set a JFrame.alwaysOnTop(true) but when I set one on top, the other one is moving to the background.

So I need something like a command where I can set one JFrame as the Background, one as the Foreground and one as something in between and it should not be switchable by clicking. Can somebody help me?

```
ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/x.png"));
ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/y.png"));
ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/z.png"));

JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame3 = new JFrame();

JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
JLabel label3 = new JLabel();

label1.setIcon(img1);
label2.setIcon(img2);
label3.setIcon(img3);

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

panel1.add(label1);
panel2.add(label2);
panel3.add(label3);

frame1.setContentPane(panel1);
frame2.setContentPane(panel2);
frame3.setContentPane(panel3);

panel1.setBorder(null);
panel2.setBorder(null);
panel3.setBorder(null);

frame1.setVisible(true);
frame2.setVisible(true);
frame3.setVisible(true);
```

The expectet result is a full screen background jframe with one big jframe in the middle of it and on top of the middle-JFrame there is another JFrame. And I dont want the JFrames to change their position.

Thank you!

Comment: Please dont explain what your code is (supposedly) doing. Rather take the time to build a minimal example that shows your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the JFrames' "FocusableWindowState" to false.

```
frame1.setFocusableWindowState(false);
frame2.setFocusableWindowState(false);
frame3.setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

To put one to the background an anotherone to the foreground you just have to set them visible in a specific order.

```
frame1.setFocusableWindowState(false);
frame2.setFocusableWindowState(false);
frame3.setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

Like that the first JFrame will be in background, the second in between and the last in foreground.

```
ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/x.png"));
ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/y.png"));
ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/z.png"));


JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame3 = new JFrame();

JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
JLabel label3 = new JLabel();

label1.setIcon(img1);
label2.setIcon(img2);
label3.setIcon(img3);

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

panel1.add(label1);
panel2.add(label2);
panel3.add(label3);

frame1.setContentPane(panel1);
frame2.setContentPane(panel2);
frame3.setContentPane(panel3);

panel1.setBorder(null);
panel2.setBorder(null);
panel3.setBorder(null);

frame1.setFocusableWindowState(false);
frame2.setFocusableWindowState(false);
frame3.setFocusableWindowState(false);

frame1.setVisible(true);
frame2.setVisible(true);
frame3.setVisible(true);
```

I hope that I could help you!